# SQL Server 2012 Express How do I pull information from one column and compare it to another with an expression restriction

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2012-express

Sorry, I'm trying to word this correctly. Essentially what I'm trying is compare one column from a table to another column from a table to check and see how many rows are in that second column. I'm using the Northwind sample database and the question is as follows.

List all customers (include `CustomerId` and `Company Name`) who have placed less than 5 orders.

- Include those customers who have placed 0 orders. Name the count field "OrderCount."
- Order by number of placed orders in reverse order.

I'm absolutely stuck on this.

Comment: what are the tables and the relationship columns betwen them

Comment: Although SQL can be daunting at first I'd suggest to rather go through something like an online SQL course and learn things step by step versus asking for a solution here and trying to figure it out.

Comment: Since you're stuck, why not post some examples of what you've tried?

Comment: Just want to say thank you to JBrooks and deroby. I'm just a small time guy looking through some sample problems. I learn a lot through disecting examples and I'm rather new to this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have the names a little off.

```
    SELECT c.CustomerId, c.[Company Name], ISNULL(OrderSum.OrderCount,0) AS OrderCount
    FROM Customers c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, Count(1) OrderCount
               FROM Orders
               GROUP BY CustomerId) OrderSum
    ON c.CustomerId = OrderSum.CustomerId
    WHERE ISNULL(OrderSum.Cnt, 0) < 6
    ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: You probably want to add `ISNULL()` around the 3th field

Answer (score 0):

Although JBrooks answer looks perfectly fine, I would have gone for this

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.[Company Name], COUNT(o.Customer_id) as OrderCount
    FROM Customer c
    LEFT JOIN Orders o
           ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.[Company Name]
    HAVING COUNT(o.Customer_id) < 6
    ORDER BY 2
```

And I'm now wondering which one is more efficient ... I'll install Northwind tomorrow if I find the time...

UPDATE: Installed Northwind and tried both JBrooks and my version. Seems they are pretty much equivalent although it's dangerous to draw conclusions on such a small dataset off cousre.

[image: QueryPlan]